# Assembly: no such instruction `iretd`? What can I use instead? i686-elf-gcc

Tags: gcc, x86, cross-compiling, att, osdev

I have written a keyboard interrupt handler where in my ASM code I have an instruction `iretd`.
When compiling the file, GCC returns an error saying

```
drivers/kbd_hndlr.S: Assembler messages:
drivers/kbd_hndlr.S:6: Error: no such instruction: `iretd'
```

I have searched on Google for solutions but I can't seem to find anything about `iretd` for the AT&T syntax.
Is there any alternative I can use instead?

kbd_hndlr.S:

```
.global keyboard_handler
.extern keyboard_main

keyboard_handler:
        call keyboard_main
        iretd
```

Comment: How about just `IRET` ?

Comment: `iretd` is just being explicit about 32-bit operand-size.  Possibly `iretl` in AT&T if there's any ambiguity.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/iret:iretd.  As usual you could just disassemble machine code into AT&T syntax to find out what syntax GAS / objdump use.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter, that fixed the issue.

Comment: With iret your code could function for 16,32,64 as written.   Over specifying (ie. iretl) limits its applicability.  That is rarely desirable.